# Javascript detecting browser. Expressions not working

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I'm trying to detect the use of Internet Explorer through Javascript. This is just practice for me, but it seems I have stumbled upon an issue with this short script, or maybe IE just hates me. Here's my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if (navigator.userAgent == /MSIE/) { //Check for expression MSIE in userAgent string.
 alert("IE Test.");
 }

 else if (navigator.userAgent !== /MSIE/) { alert("Epic Fail!! :S"); } //Just incase... Test if userAgent doesn't equal MSIE then figure out what went wrong. :S
</script>
```

For some reason navigator.userAgent is not equal to MSIE. Maybe it's my coding, or maybe IE hates me.

Thanks for the help. 
-itsports

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare to a regular expression. You need to `test` which will return `true` or `false`.

```
var ie = /msie/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if (ie) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```